# WIX and Visual Studio 2019 - No boilerplate code anymore?

Tags: wix

I just downloaded a fresh copy of WIX toolset and its extension to VS2019 on a new box. When trying the VS extension, I was disappointed to find out that the boilerplate xml code that was present in 2017 is gone now. I was wondering why they took it out -- It was very convenient.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***WiX Templates***: The image shows a WiX template - if that is what you mean by boilerplate code. Those should still be there. If you don't see them, try searching for "wix" in the "New Project" search box:

[image: New Project]

***WiX Visual Studio Extension***: If you don't see the templates, perhaps you installed the wrong Visual Studio extension? Please check again?  https://wixtoolset.org/releases/

There are also some [development releases of WiX](https://wixtoolset.org/releases/development/) (3.14). Chris Painter mentioned something about the templates missing in Visual Studio 2019 at some point. He might show up later here. I think that was for an earlier version of WiX.

**Do a reboot for good measure and verify that first?**

Comment: A reboot helped .. I don't remember what the new project option name was prior, but it was not "Setup Project for Wix" .. post reboot, I do see the templates that I saw in VS 2017. All good now, thanks.